# Magento 2: How to add custom form on category page?

Tags: magento2, template, custom-block, category-view

I am using Magento 2.1 and I am trying to add one custom form in catalog page.

I override the catalog_category_view to my custom module

and use this code

```
 <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
        <container name="category.view.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="category-view" after="-">
         <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Search\Form" name="category.pr" template="Vendor_Module::category/form.phtml">
                       </container>
    </referenceContainer>
```

buts it's not working. is there any other way to do this???

Comment: Check my answer, you did little mistake in catalog_category_view.xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create **catalog_category_view.xml** and call your custom form block

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="category.view.container">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.category.form" template="Vendor_Module::category/form.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now create custom form.phtml at

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/category/form.phtml

```
<?php

echo "<h1>Test Form on category page</h1>";
```